# Relation between Earth's rotation-gravity and moving object on Earth

Tags: newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

This might be silly question. It's about the rotation of the Earth and the objects moving on it. If I jump into the air, why did I also move with the Earth though I am in the air? I am supposed to be land in backward/forward location, as it keeps rotating. But this doesn't happen. What is this phenomenon called?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1193/2451 and links therein.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Earth moves how much under my feet when I jump?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48287/)