# Whether a ball thrown upwards will come back to the same position if we consider the effect of rotation of the earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, coriolis-effect

My friend and I had a huge debate about whether the trajectory of a projectile thrown upwards will be affected by the rotation of the earth. We finally concluded after detailed explanations that it should be independent of whether earth is rotating or not. I can't "explain" the reason here (its basically related to the fact that the centripetal force due to gravity would act on it even if it is projected).

This question can be simplified to:

> Whether a ball thrown upwards will come back to the same position if we consider the effect of rotation of the earth?

We feel it should reach the same point but then the term Coriolis force struck our minds and we got confused...Can someone clear our confusion?

**Edit**
My explanation:
When the ball is on the ground, it rotates with the earth due to the centripetal force experienced due to gravity. Similarly, when the object is in air the only difference is that it has lost contact with the earth's surface. It already has a tangential velocity as it was projected from the ground and a centripetal acceleration towards the center of the earth. Therefore, it should still rotate around the axis of the earth as it was earlier (when it was on the ground).

I now know that this doesn't happen from some posts on SE but am not clear with why this explanation is false.

Comment: See also: [If a bullet is fired vertically upwards, when it comes back does it fall to the same spot?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/166853/)

Comment: @JohnRennie That question is more of mathematics and doesn't explain why that would happen...I am editing my question again please see if it is clearer now

Comment: Your question is already clear enough. What is not clear is why you think this is a different question to the one we think it is a duplicate of. Also, you say you have a doubt about the Coriolis force, but your Edit does not mention this force.