# Revolution of the Earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, earth, relative-motion

Good day, it seems easy but I still find it difficult to understand why we return to the same spot when we jump despite the Earth revolving beneath us. Can someone explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Earth moves how much under my feet when I jump?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48287/)

Comment: The duplicate listed above, and there are many others, hopefully gives you the answer. You are asking the same question as: when I am moving at 700 km/h in an aircraft, why does the book I drop from the overhead locker fall down at my feet, rather than zoom backwards along the cabin of the plane? Because both the book and you are travelling at the same velocity.

Answer (score -2):

Because earth radius and point you jumped is from earth center point is almost same .so basically there is zero difference where have you been landed.
But if you jump further far away you will land at other point.

Comment: Then how come if I throw a ball straight up in a moving car, the ball still lands in my hands, even though the car is moving faster than the earth spins?